# Handling hotfix in gitversion

Tags: semantic-versioning, gitversion

I'm trying to understand how GitVersion works.
Here there is a snippet for 'gitversion /showconfig'

```
branches:
  develop:
    mode: ContinuousDeployment
  main:
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
  hotfix:
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
...
```

After shipping the release/1.1, my git is in this state:

- Master branch has tags 1.0.0 and tag 1.1.0.
- Develop branch is in 1.2.0-alpha.1.

Now I tried to to simulate an hotfix in production for the release 1.1.0

```
> git checkout master                                                    
> gitversion /showvariable FullSemVer                                  
1.1.0
> git checkout -b fix/1.1
> gitversion /showvariable FullSemVer                                        
1.1.0
> Add-Content -Name EmptyFile7.txt -Value 'Correction'
> git add --all;  git commit -m "fix(gitversion): modified EmptyFile7.txt"
> gitversion /showvariable FullSemVer
1.2.0-fix-1-1.1+1
```

I expected 1.1.1-fix-.... and now I don't know how to tag this fix.
For example, is this right?

```
> git checkout master
> git merge hotfix/1.1
> git tag 1.1.1
```

Should I handle all this not as a bugfix but in develop/release way?

Riccardo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right branch was **hotfix** and not **fix**

```
> git checkout master
> gitversion /showvariable FullSemVer
1.1.0
> git checkout -b hotfix/1.1.1

# Fix
> Add-Content -Path EmptyFile7.txt -Value 'Correction'
> git add --all;  git commit -m "fix(gitversion): modified EmptyFile7.txt"

> gitversion /showvariable FullSemVer                                       
1.1.1-beta.1+1
```

Now I can switch to master and approve the hotfix

```
> git checkout master
> git merge hotfix/1.1.1
> git tag 1.1.1
```

and finally merge back to develop

```
> git checkout develop
> git merge hotfix/1.1.1
```